# Prism MVVM in small Phone project just won't work....?

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, prism

In an attempt to use Prism/MVVM in a Windows Phone project I have

1. installed Prism from NuGet
2. altered the App.XAML.vb into this:

[image]
3. altered the App.XAML into this:

[image]

Before I even get started with the project, already i get these error messages:

[image]

How do I carry on with this to get this thing rolling?

Comment: That isn't valid xaml ... you have an extra `>` in your xaml.

Comment: Where do you see that extra > ?? @Mashton ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your XAML is referencing the Store Apps MVVM lib instead of the Prism.Mvvm library.

Try making your XAML look like below.

```
<mvvm:MvvmAppBase
x:Class="TestBlankPhone.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mvvm="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm">

</mvvm:MvvmAppBase>
```

And then add the constructor in your App class.  I've pasted the C# equivalent, but it looks like you're missing your initialize call as well.

```
sealed partial class App : MvvmAppBase
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @YnotDraw! Thanks for this suggestion. You're right about the reference to the other library. What's confusing to me now is: how does this library show up (suddenly?) Is there a difference in downloading from CodePLex and installing via NuGet?

Comment: ... And do I really need the InitializeComponent in the App.xaml.vb file? As it is only used for startup, and not to be a visible View. Am I right?

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I was assuming you were using NuGet for your packages. I would recommend using NuGet. Just grab the Prism.MVVM and Prism.StoreApps packages from NuGet and you should be good to go after your edits above.  If you are doing a universal app, you have to install these packages in both projects (phone+store)  As for the InitalizeComponent method, I always just leave it by default as you may need to add some additional functionality later. Let me know if I can help any further!

Comment: Thanks @YnotDraw! This is really helpful. I had copied the compiled versions out of the AdverntureWorkshop referenceproject before. Installed from NuGet now. I notice that there are slight differences: some methods have become Async for example. I hope it will  not get any more complex than that! May be I will get back to you with some question. Thanks for now!!

Comment: Not a problem! If you think my answer was sufficient, checking it as an answer would help a lot.  Thanks!  Yeah if you ever have questions, let me know and I'll try to help! Have fun!!

Comment: I did check your answer allright, i hope you will get the credits for it. At the moment I am struggeling with the "new" way to resolve the ViewModels. I will open a new question for that.

Comment: And this is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606694/prism-how-to-bind-view-to-viewmodel-that-is-located-in-a-separate-assembly